# Automatic Tilt Kinect sensor According to head position

Tags: kinect-sdk

How to tilt the Kinect sensor according to the head position

Comment: What do you mean by the "head position"?  Where it is in the FOV, how it is tilted, something else?  Why are you wanting to change the angle dynamically?

Comment: If you want to track a person dynamically means it must be needed.If the person moving from one to another place using automatic tilt we can track that person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two functions that will allow you to detect clipping of the skeleton are:

- [FrameEdges Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.frameedges.aspx)
- [Skeleton.ClippedEdges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.skeleton.clippededges.aspx)

Depending on how your application is operation you can monitor either one of these and, when clipping of the `Skeleton` is detected, adjust the [KinectSensor.ElevationAngle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.kinectsensor.elevationangle.aspx) accordingly.